# Undefined variable: Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im retrieving data from database into my Laravel admin panel, but it says undefined variable in my view.

index.blade.php is located in admin folder inside view folder

index.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layout.admin')
@section('content')
  <h3>Admin Panel</h3>

    <table class="table">

    <tbody>

        @foreach($pools as $pool)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$pool->title}}</td>
                <td>Edit
                    |
                    Delete
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

PoolDeisgnsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\PoolDesign;

class PoolDesignController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pools = PoolDesign::all();
        return view('admin.index', compact('pools'));
    }
}
```

PoolDesign.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class PoolDesign extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['title','description','area','depth','cost','image','category_id'];

    public function category(){
        $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

It gives this error when executing

> Undefined variable: pools (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jayani_pool\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)

Routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/index','PagesController@index');
Route::get('/projects','PagesController@index1');
Route::get('/services','PagesController@index2');
Route::get('/blog','PagesController@index3');
Route::get('/about','PagesController@index4');
Route::get('/contact','PagesController@index5');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/login','PagesController@login');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('admin.index');
    })->name('admin.index');

    Route::resource('pools', 'PoolDesignController');
    Route::resource('category', 'CategoriesController');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked if you are in the right controller?

Comment: check first if the controller  that  calls the view is actually your PoolDesignController. To check, try to dd($pools); before returning the view

Comment: Yes, Its PoolDesignController

Comment: @Dearwolves dd($pools); gives the same error

Comment: that's it! you're not calling the index method of your PoolDesignController

Comment: It's because the error must not exist if you dd($pools); before returning the view.

Comment: if you may please post all the route that relates to your PoolDesignController and the actual url you are calling

Comment: @Dearwolves I've edited the routes into question, the url im calling is. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the url you are calling (`/admin`) you are executing the following piece of code:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('admin.index');
    })->name('admin.index');
```

Which will try to render `admin.index` without setting the `pools` variable, thus causing the error.

If you would navigate to `/admin/pools` it would be called correctly (i.e. through the controller, where the right variables are being set). You should change your routes accordingly or edit this piece of code to also provide `$pools`.

Or you could check in your template if $pools is set with:

```
@if(isset($pools))
   // Some more html here
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your calling this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('admin.index');
    })->name('admin.index');
```

on your url. which really just direct your route to the view without going to the controller.

You can try this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        $pools = App\PoolDesign::all();
        return view('admin.index',compact('pools'));
    })->name('admin.index');
```